# shell action in oozie

Tags: shell, oozie, hue

I am creating a workflow in oozie and need to add a shell action through hue.

My shell command looks like this:

```
sudo -u test scp user@hostIP:/FILELOCATIONINremoteServer /LOCALfolder
```

How do I create this in hue?